# ~ Binary Ones Complement in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

Just had a doubt about how binary one's complement work.
For example(in python):

```
a = 60
print(~a)
```

Gives an output:-

```
-61
```

Isn't binary one's complement of `60` is :

```
a = 0011 1100
~a  = 1100 0011
```

Should it not be `-60` ?

I know I'm wrong but why does it shift ahead to `-61`?

Answer (score 11):

`~` is a bitwise inversion operator and [it acts exectly as defined](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

> The bitwise inversion of x is defined as -(x+1).

This is simply how the bitwise inversion of the [two's complement representation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) of an integer works.

The two's complement wheel visualizes this pretty well:

[image]

As you can see, the bitwise inversion of 1 is -2, the bitwise inversion of 2 is -3, ..., and the bitwise inversion of 60 will be -61.

Answer (score 4):

In all modern computers, the 2's complement binary is used for representing integers (and not the classical binary representation).
As confirmed in [Python docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> A two's complement binary is same as the classical binary
> representation for positive integers but is slightly different for
> negative numbers. Negative numbers are represented by performing the
> two's complement operation on their absolute value.

The 2's complement of a negative number, -x, is written using the bit pattern for (x-1) with all of the bits complemented (switched from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1).

**Example:**
2's complement of -15:

```
-15 => complement(x-1) => complement(15-1) => complement(14) => complement(1110) => 0001
```

Python's ~ (bitwise NOT) operator returns the 1's complement of the number.

**Example:**

```
print(~14) # Outputs -15
```

14 is (1110) in its 2's complement binary form.

Here, ~14 would invert (i.e. 1's complement) all the bits in this form to 0001.
However, 0001 is actually the 2's complement of -15.

A simple rule to remember the bitwise NOT operation on integers is -(x+1).

```
print(~60) # Outputs -61
print(~-60) # Outputs 59
```

Comment: 2's complement representation of negative integer -15 is 5'b10001. So it needs atleast 5 bits and cannot be done with 4 bits.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. `1100 0011` is actually `-61`.

Here's how a **negative** binary is converted to decimal:

1. Invert the bits
2. Add 1
3. Convert to decimal
4. Add negative sign

So:

```
1100 0011

0011 1100 <-- bits inverted

0011 1101 <-- one added

       61 <-- converted to decimal

      -61 <-- added negative sign
```

From wikipedia's [*Two's complement* page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

> The two's complement of an N-bit number is defined as its complement with respect to 2^N. For instance, for the three-bit number 010, the two's complement is 110, because 010 + 110 = 1000.

Here `1100 0011`'s complement is `0011 1101` cuz

```
    1100 0011
+   0011 1101
-------------
  1 0000 0000
```