# Binary 1's compliment in python confusion?

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to turn 1's into 0's and vice versa of a binary number, and I thought bitwise NOT (~) would do the job as I've done it before on C code, but it doesn't work like that on Python.

Example

I have a binary 'a'
`a= 0b1010 = 10`

I used '~' and I get this:
`~a=-0b1011 = -11`

But I want this:
`~a=0b0101 = 5`

what is the right way to do it?

THANKS!

Comment: It's doing exactly what you want.  It's just that Python integers use unlimited precision, so the complement of a non-negative integer contains an infinite number of leading 1 bits.  Python treats these as two's complement values, so it interprets them as negative numbers.  So `~0b1010` is `0b1111.....111110101`,  which in two's complement is just `-11`.  If you want to mask off the high-order bits, just do a bitwise AND with one less than the desired power of two.

Comment: Something like `~a & (a.bit_length() ** 2 - 1)` should work

Comment: @IainShelvington You meant `2**a.bit_length()`, not `a.bit_length()**2`.  Of course, it's simpler and more efficient to use `1<<a.bit_length()` (then subtract one).

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, yes I did. Annoyingly `4**2 == 2**4`, so my quick test passed

Comment: @TomKarzes: good explanation - is there a canonical answer for that? There's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145028/binary-ones-complement-in-python-3) but it doesn't cover masking the higher bits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a bitwise Not operation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151107/how-do-i-do-a-bitwise-not-operation-in-python)

Comment: @sj95126 It looks like the above covers it.